# Failure about the "Additional Service or Account Disclosures " when submitting the ofice add-in

Tags: office-js, office-js-store

Critical validations   1 failure(s)
These failures block the publish of your product to our marketplace.
Requirement Policies
General Content
1100.1.4 Additional Service or Account Disclosures
Your offer depends upon additional services or accounts for full functionality but does not disclose these dependencies in the description.
Please update the description and re-submit your offer.

Comment: The previous text is from the cert report.

Comment: I found the description in the https://partner.microsoft.com . The description is under "Office Store" -> "Marketplace listings".

Comment: Users need to login in or create a account when use this add-in. A website is set up for the add-in. Does it mean that I need to tell users in the descripton that one needs an account to use the add-in ? And then I need to mention the website?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Instead of adding a bunch of comments, just edit your original question.

Comment: Customer Service questions are off topic here. Please open a Customer Support ticket instead
https://aka.ms/marketplacepublishersupport 
1.    Browse topics Category: Commercial Marketplace
2.    Topic: Certification issue
3.    Next step: Review solution